# Django - I can't makemigrations due to a missing field error

Tags: django

In one of my models (projects), I've deleted a field named 'fk_user', however when I try to run migrations I get the following error.

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (fk_user)
> specified for projects

I've tried clearing all files in the migrations folder aside from **init**.py, i've cleared all migrations in the table but that doesn't resolve the issue. I've also created a new database and updated the name in the settings to this new database - however I keep getting the same error.

Where is the reference to this being held? If I run a text search on my computer, the only other file that contains it is the **init** file and i've tried deleting the reference in here and even clearing the whole file however nothing works.

Comment: Are you getting error for running `migrate` command as well?

Comment: I've started with a new database and added the field back in to find the issue - makemigrations and migrate and running fine now however when I try to visit the url containing the model's view, it gives me this error. It tells me the 'exception location' is "...python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py in __new__, line 266" - however the model file seems to make no difference, the error is raised whether i delete or add back in the field called "fk_user" through migrations, it appears unaffected.

Comment: This seems like a bug. I've tried renaming the field to 'fk_user1' and adding it back to model and now i'm told my "projects' object has no attribute 'fk_user', pointing to a line in my views.py file. However it's incorrectly stating that 'fk_user' is written on this line when it has already been changed and saved as 'fk_user1'. Some file is remembering the old name and consistently raising an error.

Comment: Quick update, i deleted this line in the views.py file, saved, re-added, saved and now the error has moved back to the 'django/forms/models.py' location